# Unexpected data truncation on HSQLDB only

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have an entity that is defined with JPA annotations (only a few fields of interest shown here)

```
@Entity
public class Rule implements Serializable, Cloneable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
            generator = "SEQ_STORE")
    @Column(name = "RULE_ID",
            nullable = false)
    private final Long id = null;

    @Column(name = "CODE",
            length = 25,
            nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION",
            length = 250,
            nullable = true)
    private String description;


    @Column(name = "VALIDATION_FIELDS",
            length = 250,
            nullable = true)
    private String validationFields;

    @ExportField("EXPRESSION")
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "EXPRESSION",
            nullable = true)
    private String expression;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "ACTION",
            nullable = true)
    private String action;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID",
            nullable = true,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_XTB_RULE_2_PARENT") )
    private Rule parent;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RULESET_ID",
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_XTB_RULE_2_RULESET") )
    private RuleSet ruleSet;

}

@Entity
public class RuleSet implements Serializable, Cloneable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7982682149517239983L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
            generator = "SEQ_STORE")
    @ExportField("RULESET_ID")
    @Column(name = "RULESET_ID",
            nullable = false)
    private final Long id = null;



    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ruleSet",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("position")
    private List<Rule> rules = new LinkedList<Rule>();
}
```

Then I have a method that generates a **tree** of these `Rule`s (see the backreference) and puts all the rules into the `List` contained in the `Ruleset` entity.

The auto-generated DDL makes columns suitable for large `expression`s as the column is `@Lob` annotated

On Mysql and Oracle I can successfully run the code that populates the rules table (I run Bamboo tests that create DB from scratch every time). Hoever, when the testing is run oh HSQLDB, Hibernate's `insert` of the `Ruleset` object fails

```
2016-04-29 13:09:26,946 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - logExceptions - SQL Error: 3401, SQLState: 22001
2016-04-29 13:09:26,949 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - logExceptions - data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: XTB_RULES column: EXPRESSION
2016-04-29 13:09:39,965 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] it.phoenix.web.data.managers.spring.ModuleManagerImpl - init       - could not execute statement
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: XTB_RULES column: EXPRESSION
...
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
```

There is an expression long 353 character in my code, I have almost found the "guilty" object.

But the problem is that even with HSQLDB the following DDL is generated

```
create table XTB_RULE_FUNCTIONS (RULE_FUNCTION_ID bigint identity not null,
     DESCRIPTION varchar(250),
     ENABLED bit not null,
     EXPRESSION varchar(MAX) not null,
     NAME varchar(50) not null,
     OBJECT_TYPE varchar(20) not null,
     POSITION bigint not null,
     primary key (RULE_FUNCTION_ID));
```

`EXPRESSION` is supposed to be `VARCHAR(max)`, so it should accommodate any string.

But my insertion still fails. I have no mean to check the actual in-memory database at the moment

Other info on the application:

- Is a web application running on Tomcat
- I use Bamboo CI to run tests on different databases, each loading the Spring context instead of being run in a servlet container
- Part of Spring initialization is to populate, along others, the Ruleset table if data does not exist. Since Bamboo recreates DB at every run (especially in-memory one), I always need to populate rules declared programmatically somewhere in a piece of code useless to paste here
- I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16712569/471213) but I have checked that DDL script declares `VARCHAR(max)` so I don't think that applies to me
- Again and again, the same code works on other DBs

Still, I need to store data larger than 255 characters

Any idea on how to fix? In my unit testing I may still comment out one of the entities, but that is only a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried specifying an explicit length for the column? @Column(name = "EXPRESSION", nullable = true, length = 100000)

Comment: No because I don't know the possible effects (I mean the generated DDL) on SQL Server, Mysql, Oracle, Pgsql. Requirement is that the app works on the 4 in production, HSQL is for CI purposes only. I could give a try and check the DDL carefully

Comment: You are definitely using the correct dialect? HSQLDB supports VARCHAR(max)?

Comment: `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>`

Comment: But now I think that for some unknown reason HSQL thinks MAX == 255

Comment: This is not the DDL as VARCHAR(max) is not supported by HSQLDB.

Comment: @fredt can you expand? The DDL was auto generated by Hibernate's SchemaCreate

Comment: It wouldn't be accepted by HSQLDB in that form.

Comment: So I start to think there could be a bug in the SchemaCreate component of Hibernate...? Everything worked with 5.0.3. After switching to 5.1.0 troubles started, but I did not notice because I did not have a unit test that worked with long `expression`s. The hard part of working with in-memory DB is that I can't really check the DB structure unlike with Oracle where you can log in and inspect how the created tables look like

Comment: @AlanHay you can post it as answer, it worked. I used column length of 10000 and it did **not** affect the DDL of other databases